# playframework multiple ports

Tags: scala, http, playframework, port

I'm new to play developing and I'm wondering if theres a way to use a different ports for a different endpoints in one app?

I couldn't find any reference for that, if someone can point me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I think it is not possible but why would you want to do that? Maybe if you explain what you want to do we could help.

Comment: I actually searched for this b/c I'd prefer to run my status checks on a separate port from the main application. Seems it's not doable, so I'm going to use a path prefix and match on that, but it's one reason I could see for thinking of more than 1 port. It looks like it could be done for my use case w/ alpakka, but w/o the goodies of the framework on the second port.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible. One App instance will work for one port only.

If you want to achieve above functionality, you want to use HTTP proxy server.

You may want to learn about them at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/HTTPServer